# How can I find a point outside a spherical polygon?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, computational-geometry

Say we have a spherical polygon consisting of a series of vertices $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_i$ on the unit sphere connected by great-circle arcs and are given a point $X$ on the unit sphere which is guaranteed to be inside the polygon (thus defining an interior). In general, the polygon may not be convex. Computationally, we could pick points and use an intersection-counting algorithm to determine whether they are inside of the polygon. But I'm wondering whether there is a point which could be directly calculated from the information given which would **not** be inside the polygon.

I haven't thought about this part as much but bonus points if you can find a point that is in some sense "far away" from the polygon.

Comment: What have you tried? What’s the context for the problem?

Comment: Hi,

As mentioned, I thought about picking points using some algorithm and testing using edge-counting. However my question is really whether there is something nicer.

I thought about picking a point antipodal to $X$ but it's easy to find a counterexample. 

My understanding is that for a convex polyhedron the centroid is inside. I haven't been able to figure out if the antipodal point is always outside.

The context of the problem is that I want to find a point outside the polyhedron that I can use to conformally stereographically project it onto a plane.

Comment: In a way, a spherical polygon does not have an "outside"; instead, it has two different "inside"s.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin According to the OP's question, there's a point $\ X\ $, not on the polygon, which distinguishes its inside "inside" from its outside "inside".

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Yes, I got that. Also yes, that's what I will call them from now on.